# How use C# to send Key Down & Key Down to another application

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, key

I have a solution that I'm using to send key inputs to another application, however when I send "Key Down" it doesn't actually hold that key down, I would need to basically spam "key down" in some kind of update loop.

I would appreciate it if anyone could show me how I might (using winforms) send a fake Key Down to another application, but I'm not looking for a keystroke.

```js
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public static void SendKeystroke(Keys k)
        {
            const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

            IntPtr WindowToFind = FindWindow(null, "application");

            IntPtr result3 = SendMessage(WindowToFind, WM_KEYDOWN, ((IntPtr)(ushort)k), (IntPtr)0);
        }

        public static void EndKeyStroke(Keys k)
        {
            const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

            IntPtr WindowToFind = FindWindow(null, "application");

            IntPtr result3 = SendMessage(WindowToFind, WM_KEYUP, ((IntPtr)(ushort)k), (IntPtr)0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When a key is held down, the application gets flooded by the message pump with [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown). Only when the key is let go is WM_KEYUP sent.

Comment: How often should I send Key Down, then? to simulate real input.